# AppleScript Google Search

Tags: search, applescript

I am trying to create an AppleScript that does a google search. 
Without a script I would simply enter 
Site:help.apple.com/ "iPhone" User Guide
into the URL bar to do a search. Naturally the quote iPhone quote is for an exact match and the User Guide is a search for either word. 
I have tried using escape codes, and I have tried leaving them out.

```
open location "site:help.apple.com/ " & "\"" & "iPhone" & "\"" & "User Guide"

open location "site:help.apple.com/ iPhone User Guide"
```

The result looks like site:help.apple.com/%20"iPhone"User%20Guide
It seems to be reading the whole thing as a single URL. 
Is there a way to get google to do a search based on the Site: string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a full google search url:

```
open location "https://www.google.com/search?q=iphone+user+guide+site%3Ahelp.apple.com"
```

Things to note:

- Escape spaces with +
- Url encoded the : character (%3A)
- Putting the 'site:' part at end

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, and thank you for the Things to note too! That really helps me.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forgot to accept the answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Cheers.